Shelley Duvall, star of The Shining, Faerie Tale Theatre, and Popeye, has passed at 75
The Rolling Stone article indicates that she's believed to have died from complications from her diabetes.

Shelley Duvall, the intrepid, Texas-born movie star whose wide-eyed, winsome presence was a mainstay in the films of Robert Altman and who co-starred in Stanley Kubrick’s “The Shining,” has died. She was 75.
Duvall died Thursday in her sleep at her home in Blanco, Texas, her longtime partner, Dan Gilroy, announced. The cause was complications of diabetes, said her friend, the publicist Gary Springer.


Maybe a few too many peripherally-involved actors?  There have been 70-odd SF authors/artists who have "passed on" so far this year, and we've only had in-memoriam posts for 3 of them.  You want me to start spamming them?  There have been several that I felt have risen to the level of "notable" that I didn't post because I was afraid they might be a bit obscure.

{nods} I honestly have just been posting them as I run into them. But I'm fine with pulling back.

She was an important actress who appeared in more than one important movie.

And I will freely admit that I am a lousy person for determining the significance of roles. I knew that she was in The Shining, and I recognized her in the Popeye images. But I'm not very good at following actors and actresses in general. They all kind of meld together in my head.

Shelley was also the executive producer and host of Faerie Tale Theatre, which did a lot for my young mind.  RIP Shelly <3
